# Why does adding a border change the position of my nav bar?

Tags: css

See this CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KypbC.

**HTML**

```
<body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}
nav {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #EEE;
/*  border: 1px solid #DDD;
*/}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.nav-inverse {
    background-color: black;
    color: lightGray;
}
```

I know it has something to do with the `line-height` property, but don't understand how it works.

Edit: I've read through the documentation of [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height), but don't understand it.

- What is a "line box"?
- What makes an inline element "replaced" vs. "not replaced"?
  ...

Comment: This isn't relative to the border. You are facing "collapsing margins" see this example with 0 margin set on the ul (remember browsers give a default margin to them) http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/yBtur

Comment: more about collapsing margins (scroll down to "Collapsing Margins Between Parent and Child Elements") http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "issue" you are facing is related to **collapsing margins** between parent and child element.

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline
> content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the
> margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline
> content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the
> margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child,
> then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the
> parent.

source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

The default styling of the `<ul>` element includes margin-top. It collapses with the parent container (`nav`) when you don't give a border to it.

This is why th `ul` element "moves" down when you set a border to it.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `display:inline-block` and always use `box-sizing:border-box` which gives border inside or it will be `100%` width  + border `2px` (right + left) so it will go beyond 100% and scroller will appear

the issue was you gave `line-height` + `padding` so the height increased

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBrCh)

Comment: Why? I'm not particularly interested in getting it to work. I'm interested in learning why things work the way they do.